# How can I overcome this list.append problem (list.pop)

Tags: python

I have come across a very interesting problem with list.append and list.pop as in the code below

```
x = [1,2]
y = []
y.append(x)
print(y)
print("------")
x.pop()
print(y)
```

Output is

```
[[1, 2]]
------
[[1]]
```

Is there any way to maintain print(y) as [[1,2]]
Thanks

**EDIT**: Also, does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: `y.append(x.copy())`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: The reference to the object is the same both in the variable `x` and in the list `y`.

Comment: In python lists are mutable secuence of objects. That means that x really is not a list, but a reference to the list, so when you do y=x,  you are only copying the reference, not the list. If you change the original list (x) the other list (y) will change too. To avoid it, as @Sanyash says, you need to use x.copy() and make another copy of the list

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
y.append(x)
```

You are adding a reference to the `x` object into the `y` list. When you do `x.pop()`, you are doing that operation on all references of `x`, which includes the one within  `y`.

To make a separate copy of that list, you can either do

```
y.append(x[:])
```

Which is a slice returning all items in the list - a copy, essentially. If you do not like this syntax and you are in Python 3, you can use

```
y.append(x.copy())
```

This may be a bit clearer in your code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/) for a few more alternatives to copy a list.